# Android: Unable to clear initial draw to SurfaceView

Tags: android, graphics, surfaceview

I've just started playing around with developing an Android app and have run into some troubles.

The intention of this testing app is to draw a square to the screen that moves towards the bottom right of the screen. Simple as that.

`MainActivity` class (current entry point) looks like so:

```
    Main Activity class (current entry point) looks like so:

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Canvas canvas;
    GameLoopThread gameThread;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //Super constructor
        gameThread=new GameLoopThread(); //Create GameLoop instance
        //Create mySurfaceView instance and pass it the new gameloop
        MySurfaceView sView=new MySurfaceView(this,gameThread);
        //Without this only the bit I cant remove is drawn
        sView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        setContentView(sView); //Set the current ContentView to the one we created
        //Pass the GameThread the MySurfaceView to repeatedly update
        gameThread.setSurfaceView(sView); 
        gameThread.start(); //Start the thread
    }
}
```

`GameLoopThread` looks like so:

```
public class GameLoopThread extends Thread {
protected volatile boolean running;
private MySurfaceView view;

public GameLoopThread(){
}

public void setSurfaceView(MySurfaceView view){
    this.view=view;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    running=true;
    while(running){
        Canvas c = null;
        c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas(); //Get the canvas
        if (c!=null) {
            synchronized (view) {
                view.draw(c); //Run the doDraw method in our MySurfaceView
            }
        }
        try {
            sleep(30, 0); //Throttle
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (c != null) {
            view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c); //Lock and post canvas
        }
    }
}

public void terminate(){
    running=false;
}
```

}

And finally `MySurfaceView` looks like so:

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView {
    private Bitmap bmp;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private final GameLoopThread gameLoop;
    Paint paint;
    float x=0;
    float y=0;

    public MySurfaceView(Context c, GameLoopThread gThread){
        super(c);
        holder=getHolder();
        gameLoop=gThread;
        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        holder.addCallback(new CallBack());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        paint.setColor(paint.getColor() - 1);
        canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + 50, y + 50, paint);
        x++;
        y++;
    }

    private class CallBack implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            gameLoop.terminate();
            while (true) {
                try {
                    gameLoop.join();
                    break;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                                   int width, int height) {
        }
    }
}
```

**The Issue**
This all works, except that one of the initial few draws to the view "sticks". It remains over top of anything drawn at a later date. See below:

[image: Overlap]

I cannot fathom why this is happening. No amount of clearing fixes the problem. If I stop drawing the 'new' square the 'stuck' square remains. You can see I'm varying the color of the 'new' square to test if it changes the 'stuck' one which would indicate it was being redraw. Clearly it isn't.

Drawing nothing for around 4 loops with a 30ms pause in between each draw results in no 'stuck' square. Starting drawing after those initial 4 results in a square that moves across the screen as it should.

Varying the pause time changes how many loops must be waited, but the relationship doesn't appear to be proportional.

**Other Info**

This is being run on a Samsung Galaxy SIII Mini

SDK verson 4.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SurfaceView has two parts, a Surface and a View.  When you get a Canvas with `lockCanvas()`, you're getting a Canvas for the Surface part.  The Surface is a separate layer, independent of the layer used for all of the View elements.

You've subclassed SurfaceView and provided an `onDraw()` function, which the View hierarchy uses to render onto the View portion.  My guess is that the View hierachy gets an invalidate and decides to draw on the View part of the SurfaceView.  Your experiment of skipping the rendering for the first few loop iterations works because you're skipping the render that happens on the invalidate.  Because the Surface layer is drawn behind the View layer, you see the `onDraw()`-rendered square on top of the other stuff you're rendering.

Normally you don't draw on the View; it's just a transparent place-holder, used by the layout code to leave a "hole" in the View layer where the Surface will show through.

Rename `onDraw()` to `doDraw()`, and drop the `@override`.  I don't think there's a reason to subclass SurfaceView at all.  That should prevent the SurfaceView from drawing on its View.

Of course, if you *want* to have a mask layer, perhaps to add rounded corners or a "dirt" effect, drawing on the View is an easy way to accomplish it.

See the [Graphics Architecture doc](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html) for the full story.

Comment: `SurfaceView` needs to be subclassed to provide both the async drawing and so it can be set as the set as the main activity's `ContentView`. Regardless, your solution does indeed work. It seems quite odd to me that the change is necessary; every tutorial I have gone through uses `onDraw()`.

Comment: The tutorials are structured incorrectly. Most of them unnecessarily lock the SurfaceHolder as well. See Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) for several uses of SurfaceView that do not involve creating subclassing; https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieSurfaceActivity.java is a pretty straightforward example.

Comment: Actually, "multi-surface test" (https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/MultiSurfaceActivity.java) is probably a better example. It's software-rendered from a dedicated thread, and features multiple overlapping SurfaceVIews.

Comment: @faddem 
Ah yes, I see. You are completely correct that I need not subclass `SurfaceView`. Great example by the way, bookmarking that.